# Is every open set a continuous image of a closed set? (in Euclidean space)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset.

> The question is whether $A$ can always be written as a continuous
>   image of a closed subset of euclidean space
>
> $f(C) = A$ for some closed subset $C \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ (for some $m$).

So far I have been able to verify that it is true for open balls and the whole space and it seems to me like it must hold but i cant figure out how to approach proving it.

Additionally if it is indeed true i'd like to know if there are any other more general spaces for which this applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true for $m =n+1$.

First show that every (nonempty) open set can be written as a countable (increasing) union of compact sets

$$
U = \bigcup K_\ell
$$

Now set

$$
A = \bigcup K_\ell \times \{\ell\}. 
$$

I leave it to you to verify that $A \subset \Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ is closed and that the continuous function

$$
f : \Bbb{R}^n \times \Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}^n, (x,y) \mapsto x
$$
does the job.

Answer (score 0):

We can write $A=\bigcup B_n$ as a countable union of closed (say) balls and then map disjoint, separated (that is, distance $\ge\delta>0$ apart) closed sets $C_n$ onto these balls $B_n$ and take $C=\bigcup C_n$.

If desired, we can also extend $f$ continuously to all of $\mathbb R^n$ by Tietze's extension theorem.

We also see that this works for arbitrary $m,n$; if $n<m$, then we have to work with Peano curve like maps.