# If $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set. Show that $A = \bigcup K_\ell \times \{\ell\}$ is a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The question arises from the proof in this thread - [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990880/is-every-open-set-a-continuous-image-of-a-closed-set-in-euclidean-space)

Given an open set $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$. We know that it can be written as a countable union of compact sets - $U = \bigcup K_\ell$.

Let us define $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that $A = \bigcup K_\ell \times \{\ell\}.$

> Show that A is a closed set

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Hint: a convergent sequence in $A$ is of the type $(x_j,l_j)$ with $x_j \in K_{l_j}$. If this sequence converges then the second coordinates must converge. But  a sequence of integers can converge only if it becomes constant after some stage. This means there is an integer $l$ such that $x_j \in K_l\times {l}$ for all $j$ large enough. Rest is clear by compactness of $K_l$.